# `extern` declarations and following defintions of class template instances with and without parameter lists

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider following code:

```
template <typename T = int> struct X {};
extern X foo;
X foo;
```

<kbd>[Live on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/UWsEYd)</kbd>

I would expect it to be well-formed, but GCC, Clang and MSVC reject it with following error messages:

GCC 8.2 (with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`):

> ```
> <source>:3:3: error: conflicting declaration 'X foo'
>  X foo;
>    ^~~
> <source>:2:10: note: previous declaration as 'X<int> foo'
>  extern X foo;
>           ^~~
> ```

Clang 7.0.0 (with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`):

> ```
> <source>:2:10: error: declaration of variable 'foo' with deduced type 'X' requires an initializer
> extern X foo;
>          ^
> ```

MSVC Pre 2018 (with `/std:c++latest`):

> ```
> <source>(2): error C2641: cannot deduce template argument for 'X'
> <source>(3): error C2133: 'foo': unknown size
> <source>(3): error C2641: cannot deduce template argument for 'X'
> ```

---

Now the interesting part.

This snippet is accepted by Clang but rejected by GCC & MSVC:

```
extern X<> foo;
X foo;
```

And this snippet is accepted by GCC but rejected by Clang & MSVC:

```
extern X foo;
X<> foo;
```

This one is accepted by all three compilers:

```
extern X<> foo;
X<> foo;
```

And finally this one is accepted by GCC & Clang but rejected by MSVC:

```
X foo;
```

**What's going on here? Which of these five snippets are correct?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang is right in all five of your snippets.

> ```
> extern X<> foo; // type: X<>
> X foo; // CTAD => type: X<>
> ```

`foo` is only a declaration of `foo`, which is then later redeclared with the same type, so gcc and MSVC are wrong to reject this case.

> ```
> extern X foo; // invalid
> X<> foo; // ok => type: X<>
> ```

gcc is wrong here. `foo` is not a definition, only a declaration without an initializer, and thus isn't a [initializing declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#22) as is required for CTAD ([[dcl.class.type.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct)).

> ```
> extern X<> foo; // type: X<>
> X<> foo; // type: X<>
> ```

This is similar to 1), only that CTAD is not required. As the second `foo` is just a redeclaration of `foo` and defines it at the same time with the same type, it's valid.

> ```
> X foo;
> ```

MSVC is wrong here, the standard doesn't place any restriction on CTAD at global scope.

In conclusion, we can infer that your original snippet is ill-formed because you are using CTAD for a variable that is not defined.